# JTable : how to get selected cells?

Tags: swing, jtable, cell, selected

I have a JTable and its TableModel, it works well but what I want to do now is to get the selected cells of it. I thought of doing something like :

```
int rows = this.getTable().getRowCount();
int columns = this.getTable().getColumnCount();
for(int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < columns ; j++)
    {
         if(table.getCell(i,j).isSelected() //...
    }
}
```

But of course something like this doesn't exist. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In JTable, you have the

```
JTable.getSelectedRow()
```

and

```
JTable.getSelectedColumn()
```

You can try combine this two method with a MouseListener and a KeyListener.
With the KeyListener you check if user is pressing the CTRL key, which means that user is selecting cells, then with a mouse listener, for every click you store maybe in a Vector or ArrayList the selected cells:

```
//global variables
JTable theTable = new JTable();//your table
boolean pressingCTRL=false;//flag, if pressing CTRL it is true, otherwise it is false.
Vector selectedCells = new Vector<int[]>();//int[]because every entry will store {cellX,cellY}

public void something(){
   KeyListener tableKeyListener = new KeyAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_CTRL){//check if user is pressing CTRL key
            pressingCTRL=true;
         }
      }

      @Override
      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
         if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_CTRL){//check if user released CTRL key
            pressingCTRL=false;
         }
      }
   };

   MouseListener tableMouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         if(pressingCTRL){//check if user is pressing CTRL key
            int row = theTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());//get mouse-selected row
            int col = theTable.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());//get mouse-selected col
            int[] newEntry = new int[]{row,col};//{row,col}=selected cell
            if(selectedCells.contains(newEntry)){
               //cell was already selected, deselect it
               selectedCells.remove(newEntry);
            }else{
               //cell was not selected
               selectedCells.add(newEntry);
            }
         }
      }
   };
   theTable.addKeyListener(tableKeyListener);
   theTable.addMouseListener(tableMouseListener);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

[table.getSelectedRow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow%28%29) will get selected row.

[table.getSelectedColumns()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedColumns%28%29) will get selected columns.

[getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29) will give the value present at the selected row for each column.

Comment: I think he wants to catch all pressed cells, not only one pressed cell

Comment: @Harlandraka is right, I have a table like a spreadsheet so I can choose many cells.

Comment: @Rob Okay. So I think even I have to try this to get all the selected cells.

Comment: @Rob check out my solution, it does what you need

Answer (score 3):

JTable has methods to [get the selected rows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRows%28%29) and [get the selected columns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedColumns%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
int row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
int col = table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
```

You can get the row and column with ( `table.getSelectedRow()` and `table.getSelectedColumn()`) but if you selected more than one cell the method `table.getSelectedRow()` and `table.getSelectedColumn()` return cell's position of the first cell that was clicked.

On the other hand, `table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint())` and `table.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint())` return the exact cell's table that was clicked for the last time.