# Get Position of a selected JTable cell?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JFrame with a few JTables. On one certain JTable, I need the position of the cell in the JFrame that is selected (selection done via code), as soon as it is selected. I would like to draw something here on a Glass Pane. How can I accomplish this?

```
Point p = gui.rerouteTable.getLocation();
SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p,gui.rerouteTable);
```

I thought this could get me the upper left hand corner of the table. And via Cell Height and the SelectionListener I could claculate the position i need. But i ca´t even get the uppper left hand corner of the table. Why not? The gui.rerouteTable.getLocation() return (0,0) so obviously the convertPointToScreen is not working correctly.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416188/jtable-how-to-get-selected-cells

Comment: @SilviuBurcea that is a different question.  This question is about the location in the frame, not what is selected.

Answer (score 14):

Use JTable's method

```
public Rectangle getCellRect(int row, int column, boolean includeSpacing)
```

Comment: Will this return the postion in the Table itself or in the entire Window?

Comment: @HansEn I don't know, but check it out and if it's relative to table, add the table offset relative to window.

Comment: In table. You can use public static void convertPointToScreen(Point p,Component c) and public static Point convertPoint(Component source,int x, int y,Component destination) methods of SwingUtilitites

Comment: there are another two ways, see Oracle tutorial How to use Tables or List - about tooltip, or ListSelectionListener with SINGLE_...,

Comment: The Problem is the GridBagLyout which changes the sizes of the Tables. And of Course the Splitpanes teh Jtbales are placed in. So the relative position is not a fixed value. .convertPoint(...) will not work, because I do not have the component of the cell..

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the glass pane for other reasons, also consider a [custom cell renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) that uses the value of `isSelected` to condition the renderer's appearance.

Addendum: Each time a `TableCellRenderer` is invoked for a particular cell, the parameter named `value` is a reference to the `Object` obtained from the model for that cell.

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented a renderer. But i do need the glass pane.

Comment: OK; here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14429388/230513) of using `getCellRect()`.

Comment: But i do need the glass pane ---> maybe you would need layout JLabel over JTables cell, nobody knows

Comment: My cellrenderer does extend JLabel. But If I try to to (JLabel)Jtable.getModel.getValueAt(0,0) I get an Exception String cannot be cast to JLabel.

Comment: It sounds like the `value` seen by the renderer's `getTableCellRendererComponent()` method is a `String`, but the default render itself is a `JLabel`, which is reused for each applicable cell. More above.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can get the x and y coordinates of a cell in a table:

```
private void jtTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    int x = jtTable.getSelectedRow();
    int y = jtTable.getSelectedColumn();
}
```