# How to get selected value from Jtable when unknown the row&column number?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

As question in title, I need to get selected value of a cell from my jtable, the function "table.getSelectedValueAt(row,column)" is not useful in my state because I don't know which row and column will user select?

Comment: Have you looked at [`getSelectedColumn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedColumn--) and [`getSelectedRow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow--)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416188/jtable-how-to-get-selected-cells

Comment: its work, thank you so much !